# ffmpeg trim .mp3 - output length forced to 2 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, trim

I have just downloaded the latest version of ffmpeg and I am trying to trim the first 14 and the last 6 seconds from a 40 seconds .mp3 file.

The problem I have is that doesn't matter what `-t X` I use, the output is always only 2 seconds in length. It's my first using ffmpeg but it seems like something is forcing it to limit the output to 2 seconds.

I tried a lot of commands including

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i input.mp3 -ab 32k -t 00:00:20.04 -c:a copy output.mp3 -y

ffmpeg -ss 14 -i input.mp3 -ab 32k -t 20 -c:a copy output.mp3 -y

ffmpeg -ss 14 -i input.mp3 -t 20 -acodec copy output.mp3 -y

ffmpeg -ss 14 -i input.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp3 -y

ffmpeg -ss 14 -t 20 -i input.mp3 output.mp3

ffmpeg -ss 14 -i input.mp3 -t 20 output.mp3
```

but the result is almost always a 2 sec mp3 file. 
Now I'm out of ideas.

As requested this is the output from the console:

```
> Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration: 00:00:40.49, start:
> 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate= 752.3kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 110.287079%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -t 5 -c:a copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 0000000002fb02c0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 0000000002fb02c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -c:a copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -t 5 -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 Trailing options were found on the commandline. [mp3 @ 0000000003020300] Skipping 0
> bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @ 0000000003020300] Estimating duration from
> bitrate, this may be inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':  
> Duration: 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -c:a copy -t 5
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 00000000003102c0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 00000000003102c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358  -t 5 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -c:a copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 0000000002fb02c0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 0000000002fb02c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -i "C:\Track7.mp3"-ss 00:00:14.358 -acodec copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 C:\Track7.mp3-ss: No such file or directory
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -ss 00:00:14.358 -acodec copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 0000000002fb0240] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 0000000002fb0240] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A video:0kB audio:0kB
> subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
> unknown Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t /
> -frames parameters if used)
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -c:a copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 0000000002fb0220] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 0000000002fb0220] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -ab 32k -c:a copy
> "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c)
> 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)  
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads
> --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 0000000002fb02c0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 0000000002fb02c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
> 
> C:\Je>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.358 -i "C:\Track7.mp3" -ab 32k -t
> 00:00:20.04 -c:a copy "C:\Track7.mp3" -y ffmpeg version
> N-75463-g53e8bef Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built
> with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3
> --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame
> --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable
> -libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --e nable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  3.100 /
> 57.  3.100   libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 / 
> 2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 [mp3 @ 00000000031903c0] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0. [mp3 @
> 00000000031903c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be
> inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Duration:
> 00:00:40.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Track7.mp3':   Metadata:
>     TSSE            : Lavf57.2.100
>     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> size=      32kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s video:0kB
> audio:32kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
> overhead: 1.410433%
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: full console output please?

Answer (score 0):

The following work for me. Here is first 14 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ab 32k -c:a copy -t 00:00:14 output.mp3 -y
```

Last 4 seconds (start from 6 seconds before end -> 40-6=34):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:34 -i input.mp3 -ab 32k -c:a copy -t 00:00:06 output.mp3 -y
```